# WebDataGrid sorting with a generic list

Tags: asp.net, infragistics, webdatagrid

I have a generic collection like this

```
Dim List(Of t) myData = data.GetData()
myWebDataGrid.DataSource = myData
myWebDataGrid.DataBind()
```

the config of the webdatagrid sort is this

```
<Behaviors>
   <ig:Sorting Enabled="true" SortingMode="Multi">
      <ColumnSettings>
          <ig:SortingColumnSetting ColumnKey="Key1" Sortable="true" />
      </ColumnSettings>
   </ig:Sorting>
</Behaviors>
```

but when I set the sortable property on this control and run the page...
I just try to sort and all the data disappears.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I realized that after the postback I have to set the data again.

Answer (score 2):

Yes the grid expects to have datasource on every postback. Or you can try to set EnableDataViewState="true"

Comment: Does not work I tried every viewstate property. Only set the datasource again on every page_load helps.